# Win-10: Odd disk usage (not access) results (2x the underlying files)

Tags: windows-10

I've got a Win-10 that was upgraded from a Win-7 on a Thinkpad.

Under Local Disk (C:) right click >> Properties, I see 44.8GB of space used.  If I open the disk, select all folders, and right click >> Properties, I get 24.4GB.  This is perplexing me.  The recycle bin is empty, if that's an issue.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are lots of system files and hidden files and possibly folders you don’t have access to that will not show up in your calculations. Use a tool like `WinDirStat` and run it as admin to see where your space is used.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems Windows.old is larger than reported, by 18GB.